# Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог самостоятельно менять данные своим сообщением?

Tags: telebot, telegram, бот

имею простенького бота, но не хочу лезть каждый раз для изменения в нем каких-либо данных. я хочу чтобы пользователь написал сообщение 'изменить кассу', программа написала ему "ваше следующее сообщение изменить данные в 'Касса'":
Пользователь записывает туда свое сообщение и после этого оно сохраняется в переменную, а после выводится командой /касса:
Мои попытки:

```py
if message.text == "изменить кассу":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'ваше следующее сообщение будет записано в кассу, будьте внимательны')
    msg1 = message.text

if message.text == "касса":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg1)
```

Понятное дело, что при наборе "касса", мне выдаст бот выдаст тоже касса, а как сделать так, чтобы он перестал записывать данные, а записывал их только тогда, когда написано 'изменить кассу', заранее спасибо за помощь, надеюсь мой вопрос понятен.